# Navigation Drawer is hidden by other ListView / Navigation Drawer prevents clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a strange Navigation Drawer behavior. When I am using the following layout, when I open the Navigation Drawer, it opens behind the listView1 and adlay. This means the drawer is partially hidden by listView1 and adlay.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/header_bg"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#eee"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adlay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, if I were to change the ordering a little, and use the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/header_bg"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adlay"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp">
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/adlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#eee"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        >
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, the Navigation Drawer will open in front (on top of) listView1 and adlay, and works well. But there is a huge problem, even when the drawer is not open, clicks on listView1 and adlay are disabled! I cannot click on anything except on the toolbar!

Below is part of my activity file:

```
    // get list items from strings.xml
    drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.autoscroll_text);

    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.storylist_navigation_drawer_item, drawerListViewItems));

    // App Icon
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

                drawerView.bringToFront();
                getWindow().getDecorView().requestLayout();
                getWindow().getDecorView().invalidate();
        }
    };

    // Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    // just styling option add shadow the right edge of the drawer
    drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

I have spent hours trying to get this to work correctly. Please note that I have a toolbar, and I need to have the drawer display below the toolbar (which is currently how it behaves).

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your drawer layout has a frame that matches parent, but doesn't have anything in it, so if you click outside of your list in your drawer it is going to actually be "touching" the frame layout. Not that that is necessarily it, I just glanced over it, but something to look into.

Comment: @zgc7009 You are right, I think the content_frame does nothing. I have just removed it, but still, clicking on anything doesn't do a thing, other than clicking on the Navigation Drawer items. I am referring to the second layout. Clicking on listView1 and adlay.still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Your drawer is taking focus somehow. Potentially the list is taking focus? Your DrawerLayout should use the wrap_content width setting instead of match_parent.

Comment: When I use android:layout_width="wrap_content", or android:layout_width="240dp", I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listview and adlay should be place inside the drawerlayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/header_bg"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/adlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adlay"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="3dp">
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#eee"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">
    </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, moving listView1 and adlay into content_frame does the trick! Thanks so much. However, this creates another problem. adlay now displays above listView1 and stays on top of listView1 covering part of it. I actually wanted to have adlay display below listView1 at the very bottom. The order from top to bottom should be: Toolbar > listView1 > adlay. Any help, please?

Comment: Change framelayout to relativelayout

Comment: I changed FrameLayout to RelativeLayout, fixed the problem, but not before re-ordering listView1 and adlay. Now I put adlay > listView1 and in listView1, I have android:layout_above="@+id/adlay" to get the desired result. All good now, thanks.

Comment: I have another question. If I wanted to programmatically add menu items to this Navigation Drawer, how do I do that? I searched on the Internet, almost everybody mentions the use of NavigationView, which I am not using in my case.

Comment: you could use getAdapter() from listview https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter() and parse it to arrayAdapter, and use add(), https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T) or addAll()

Comment: I am facing another problem with this layout .. if you have a minute please help me out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40380015/listview-drops-to-the-bottom   Thanks.

Comment: Use match_parent in the layout_height of the listview

Comment: Using match_parent in the layout_height of listView1 fixes the problem. Thank you so much.